# I need two timers working in the same View Controller ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with two timers running in the same View Controller. I need one of them to launch when the other is invalidated and go back on after the start button for the first is tapped again. I tried creating two variables and it builds successfully, but the behavior is erratic. What would be the right approach? Thanks

```
@IBAction func Start(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    timer2.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}




@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

    timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("increaseTimer")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a sort of "flip flop" timer effect?

Hav you thought about replacing `var timerHasFinishedRunning: Bool = false` with checking the invalidation?

e.g.

```
// When you invalidate, rather
timer1.invalidate()
timer1 = nil

// As goes for timer2
timer2.invalidate()
timer2 = nil
```

That way, you can have your timer checking done view computed properties:

```
var timer1HasFinishedRunning: Bool {
    return self.timer1 == nil
}

var timer1HasFinishedRunning: Bool {
    return self.timer2 == nil
}
```

Also you mention that they behave "erratically", could you elaborate? Your timer interval is 1 second, so if anything erratic happens, "within 1 second" it's probably because of the long interval. e.g. the checking of each is only done once per second, so sometimes could take as long as 1.999999 seconds to notice that a timer was invalidated.

Personally, I'd have the interval at 0.1 rather than 1.0 for greater accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may use it for my app. Now I can't figure out what is wrong with the below simple flipflop timers code. If I run it, I have Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT crash (it's not the mere misassigning case). If I remove Timer 2. The Pause works just fine (I edited my example). Thanks!

Comment: something else I just noticed, in your timer2, you have the selector set to `Selector(("increaseTimer"))` whereas it should be `#selector(ViewController.increaseTimer)`

Comment: I tried this. Error message:  "Type ViewController has no member 'increaseTimer'"